# How does one bound the growth of the support of local operators in the Transverse-Field Ising Chain?

Tags: quantum-information, spin-chains

Consider the transverse-field Ising chain (TFIC) in a transverse-field $B$:

$$H_{TFIC}(B)\equiv -\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sigma^x_j\sigma^x_{j+1}+B\sum_{j=1}^N \sigma^z$$

At $B=0$, we have the classical Ising chain, and so there is a set of groundstates for this system with zero entanglement, namely the all-up and all-down states, respectively.

Let's try to understand the ferromagnetic phase of this model: we start by adiabatically turning on $B$, represented by the time-dependent unitary evolution operator $U(B)$ defined below:

$$U(B)\equiv \lim_{T\to \infty}\mathcal T\exp\left(-i\int_0^Tdt\, H(tB/T) \right)$$

From the perspective of the groundstate subspace, because the ferromagnetic phase $B<1$ of the TFIC is gapped, then $U(B)$ must be a local unitary (LU) operator as long as $B<1$:

$$|\psi_0(B)\rangle \,=U(B)|\uparrow\rangle^{\otimes N},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,~~~~~|\psi_1(B)\rangle \,=U(B)|\downarrow\rangle^{\otimes N}$$

Since $U(B)$ is a LU operator, the symmetry-broken groundstates $|\psi_0(B)\rangle, |\psi_1(B)\rangle$ of the transverse-field Ising chain are short-range entangled (SRE) states.

My question is about the **Heisenberg picture** for the ferromagnetic phase of the TFIC, which is a much more general viewpoint from the perspective of calculating observables. An observable (e.g. magnetization) at $B\neq 0$ looks like

$$\langle\uparrow|^{\otimes N}U^\dagger (B)\, \sigma^x_j\, U(B)|\uparrow\rangle^{\otimes N}$$

Let's now just examine the operator in the middle:

$$\sigma^x_j(B) \equiv U^\dagger (B)\, \sigma^x_j\, U(B)$$

Clearly, since the TFIC is short-range entangled, $\text{supp}(\sigma^x_j(B))$ decays exponentially with distance from $j$. **At $B=0$, the support vanishes except at $j$. How quickly does this support grow as $B<1$ increases from zero**?

Comment: The constants you get in the LR bound are easy to compute: The proof is constructive.  Maybe you want to know the *real* velocity with which information can spread in the TFIM?

Comment: I guess a simple example is the unequal time commutator of $\sigma^z_j$ with $\sigma^z_k$. This should uniformly vanish at B=0, but then become some exponentially decaying function for nonzero B. Anything that captures that B-dependence is helpful. Perhaps I need to rewrite the question.

Comment: Just rewrote the question.

Comment: This is quite a different question now! It is not even clear how LR-bounds would help here.  One could instead do quasi-adiabatic evolution (to which a LR-bound would apply), but this does sth. different to operators.  What are you actually interested in?

Comment: On a different note, it is not clear to me whether the $U$ is well-defined the way you define it.  (Not even when asking for its action on some quasi-local algebra of operators.)

Comment: It seems that Hastings has a result related to this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0503554.pdf However, I can't seem to parse the paper to provide a concrete result. In particular, his correlation length "$\zeta$" does not seem to vanish as $B\to 0$, so the bound is actually quite weak. Perhaps you might understand more than I do

Comment: Quasi-adiabatic evolution is different from what you are asking: It evolves the ground state properly, but unlike adiabatic evolution it does not preserve excited states.  So, as said above, the question is: "What are you *really* interested in?"

Comment: Ok then how about the support of sigma^z after adiabatic evolution?

Comment: That was not my point.  My point is: You probably don't want to know this just for the sake of it, but because you need it for sth. else.  What do you need it for? Depending on that, one might see whether e.g. quasi-adiabatic continuation would also work.

Comment: I am curious about the growth of entanglement in the quantum ferromagnetic phase of the Ising chain. At B = 0, the system is classical, so the entanglement has zero range. At B not equal to zero, the system is SRE. How does this entanglement grow with B?

Comment: Ah, that's an entirely different question.  I'm pretty sure that this is known.  (It all maps to free fermions, so it's likely one can even analytically derive the whole entanglement spectrum.)

Comment: Interesting, do you have a paper I can look at that directly addresses this question?

Comment: None I know of, I can try searching if I have some time.  But I assume you did that already?

Comment: To ask more precisely: Do you want to know the entanglement entropy $S(rho)$ of the reduced state of the half-infinite chain? Or sth. different?

Comment: Not yet, I'm new to this entanglement business (as you can see by my naive attempts to find proxies for "the range" of entanglement), so I wouldn't know what to search.

Comment: Hm. It is not entirely clear how to define the "range" of entanglement -- some definitions come to mind, but I'm not sure they make sense.  What probably can be and has been computed is the *amount* of entanglement if you cut the state in half.  Not sure if that quantifies what you're after.

Comment: Well, I guess Xiao Gang Wen throws around the terms LRE (long-range entangled) and SRE (short-range-entangled) states, so I naively thought that that means entanglement can be given a "range". I agree I have never seen a definition of this